# Add a specific word to end of line

Tags: sed

I want to add specific word in end of the line in my file.
My file is `mac.txt` containing,

```
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74
```

I want to add `:p=abcde` to the end.
I tried:

```
cat mac.txt | sed '$/:p=1234' > mac2.txt
cat mac.txt | sed -e 's/$/:p=1234/' > mac2.txt
sed 's/$/:p=1234/' mac.txt > newmac.txt
sed 's/\(.*\)/\1:p=1234/' < mac.txt > outfile.txt
```

but what they are doing is adding text to next line like

```
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74
:p=abcde
```

I want my output to be:

```
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74:p=abcde
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The second approach should work.

Comment: Even tried this same problem sed -i "s/$/:p=1234/" mac.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '/00-1E-B8-05-7C-74/ {$0=$0":p=abcde"} 1' file
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74:p=abcde
```

It will add `:p=abcde` after lines with `00-1E-B8-05-7C-74`

---

Update:

```
awk '$0~m {$0=$0":p=abcde"} 1' m=$(cat mac.txt) file
```

Comment: I'll try awk , but instead of 00-1E-B8-05-7C-74 , i want to read contennt from mac.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. The first command should fail since that is not a valid `sed` expression.
2. The second command should work.
3. The third command should work.
4. The fourth command is overkill but should work too.

Demonstration:

```
$ cat mac.txt
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74
$ cat mac.txt | sed '$/:p=1234' > mac2.txt
sed: 1: "$/:p=1234": invalid command code /
$ cat mac.txt | sed -e 's/$/:p=1234/' > mac2.txt
$ cat mac2.txt
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74:p=1234
$ sed 's/$/:p=1234/' mac.txt > newmac.txt
$ cat newmac.txt
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74:p=1234
$ sed 's/\(.*\)/\1:p=1234/' < mac.txt > outfile.txt
$ cat outfile.txt
00-1E-B8-05-7C-74:p=1234
$
```